# Sending Post data to a webserver - Android

Tags: android, post, webserver, request

I would like to send a POST request to a webserver. I used a webhosting service before and changed to a managed server. Now I get this message in the Log File of the Webserver:

> xxx.xx.xxx.xx - - [31/Jul/2013:14:26:47 +0200] "POST /phpScript.php HTTP/1.1" 200 59622 "-" "Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE (java 1.4)" "www.wpxxxxxxx.server-xx.xx"

The script should send a mail but I never received a mail. The POST request is sent by an Android application.
I hope you can give me a clue to solve this problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17025296/what-is-apache-httpclient-unavailable-error-android-google-app-engine

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the answers on this thread - [Android HTTP User Agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3904467/android-http-user-agent).

It looks like the post is getting received (you wouldn't have a log statement server side if not). The user-agent is just automatically set as they if not explicitly changed.

Comment: This might work. I will check it as soon as possible.

Comment: While on the topic, you might check out this http library - http://loopj.com/android-async-http/